# Make Django forms use comma as decimal separator

Tags: django

I am writing a Django app for use in a country where they use comma as [decimal separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator).  I have a model that contains a [`django.db.models.DecimalField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield), and I use [model forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/modelforms/).  How can I make the resulting form field render using comma and accept comma back from the user?

Following the [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3204038/revisions) of [jweyrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298054/jweyrich), I have upgraded my application from Django 1.1 to Django 1.2 and edited my `settings.py` to contain the following:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'nb'
LANGUAGES = (
  ('nb', 'Norwegian'),
)
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = ','
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = ' '
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
)
```

As far as I can see, this is all that [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/i18n/localization/#format-localization) calls for.  It now works for forms if I set `localization=True` on the form field.  It works in neither [model forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) nor [the admin site](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/), however.

I discovered a [Django ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13032) and a resulting [Django changeset](http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/12867) from before the 1.2 release.  If I am understanding them correctly, it used to be the case that the widgets used format localization automatically, but after this patch localization has to be turned on explicitly by giving the `localization=True` keyword parameter to the form field.  Is there a way to make admin forms set `localization=True` on their fields?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, localization does need to be turned on explicitly for every field.  For a model form (including the ones used in the admin app), a convenient way to do this is to subclass ModelForm and turn on localization for each DecimalField:

```
import django

class LocalizedModelForm(django.forms.ModelForm):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        new_class = super(LocalizedModelForm, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        for field in new_class.base_fields.values():
            if isinstance(field, django.forms.DecimalField):
                field.localize = True
                field.widget.is_localized = True
        return new_class
```

Then you can define your custom ModelForm class and use it in the admin app:

```
class FooForm(LocalizedModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Foo


django.admin.site.register(Foo, form=FooForm)
```

Comment: Brilliant and elegant solution.

Comment: I would prefer making it a mixin: `LocalizationMixin(object): ...` and `FooForm(LocalizationMixin, forms.ModelForm)`, so you can keep using e.g. `FooForm(LocalizationMixin, floppyforms.ModelForm)`

Comment: What if you want to enable localization directly for Models? Not ModelForms. Use case: View responding to an AJAX HTTP request posting data, and want to store that data (containing numbers with comma as thousand separator) in a Model with a Decimal field. Can't find a solution for that.

Answer (score 10):

In django >= 1.6 there is a simple solution to this:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class YourModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        localized_fields = '__all__'

django.admin.site.register(YourModel, form=YourModelForm)
```

[See the official documentation for a more verbose explanation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#enabling-localization-of-fields)

Comment: And for forms.Form, `forms.DecimalField(label='Foo', localize=True)` works.

Comment: redundant parentheses surrounding '__all__'

Answer (score 7):

Right, this looks like an annoying breakage that I'm surprised no-one has reported. Because of the change you mention, localization has to be explicitly turned on for every field in your admin app or model form. The best way to do this would be to define a custom ModelForm for use both in the admin and in your app, and set the `widgets` dictionary to enable localization on each relevant field.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'my_decimal_field': forms.TextInput(attrs={'localization': True}),
        }
```

Comment: That only sets an attribute in the HTML, but you put me on the right track (a custom ModelForm turned out to be the way to go), so you get the bounty.  Thanks!  I'll post the working solution as a separate answer.