# Django's DecimalField representation in admin as 0,00 values

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I want to represent a price in my model in the form of 0,00. This is the part of my model.

`price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.00'))`

However, prices such as `2.10` are still represented as `2.1`.

The second issue would be to replace the `.` with a `,`. However `default=Decimal('0,00')` of course is not possible since `,` is not a valid literal for Decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your field in your database state `decimal(5,2)`

And check out this SO answer regarding [replacing the decimal point with a comma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3430023/538471).

Comment: Hello dan, 

Thanks for your comment. I'm using sqlite for the database. In that database the price as DecimalField is represented through an integer field. As far as I know there is not field type decimal in sqlite, or?

So what to do?

Comment: I don't have much experience with sqlite. But I think Django will store your decimal values as strings. Maybe you should consider using a database like MySQL instead.