# How to allow user to input comma

Tags: django

I have a modelform for transaction. That transaction model has a field for amount (DecimaField). When I try to enter **1,000** it doesn't allow me to save the data but no error shown, it just refresh. I try to put localize in the modelform but still it doesn't allow me.

How to allow the form to accept the comma (1,000)?

Here are my codes:

**forms.py**

```
class AddTransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    amount = forms.DecimalField(localize=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        exclude = ('envelope', 'uid',)

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddTransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        //other codes here
```

**views.py**

I tried also in views to replace comma before it totally save but it gives me an error.

```
def transaction(request):   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['process'] == 'addtrans':
            tform = AddTransactionForm(request.user, 
                                       request.POST)
            if tform.is_valid():
                if request.POST['type'] == 'withdrawal':
                    trans = tform.save(commit=False)
                    trans.amount = 0 - trans.amount
                    trans.save()
                    messages.success(request,
                        "Transaction created successfully.")
                else:
                    trans = tform.save()
                    messages.success(request,
                        "Transaction created successfully.")

                if not trans.account:
                    env = Envelope.objects.get(
                        user=request.user,
                        name='Unallocated Income')
                    trans.envelope = env
                    trans.save()
                    env.amount += trans.amount
                    env.save()
                    messages.success(request, 
                        "Unallocate income save")               
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('transactions:transaction'))    

    return render(request, 'trans_list.html', {
        .........
    })
```

I don't want to modified my model. Is there a way in forms or views?

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203089/make-django-forms-use-comma-as-decimal-separator will be helpful?

Comment: @EllochkaCannibal I already tried that but no effect. Maybe there is a change in Django 1.4

Comment: Please show your entire view code.  The fact that an error is not rendered indicates a problem in your view.  The error message may indicate something other than an error with commas such as a numbered entered with incorrect precision.

Comment: @catherine The view function you posted is rather long with many different code paths.  Can you create a minimal view function that shows just the issue with commas in your input?  eg One form on the page, calls to `is_valid()`, rendering.

Comment: @AustinPhillips finish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick and dirty fix to handle the situation you describe, you could copy the `request.POST` querydict at the beginning of the view, remove the offending commas from the input, and pass your adjusted querydict to form constructor -

```
def transaction(request): 
    if request.POST.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST.copy()
        if 'amount' in post:
            post['amount'] = pos['amount'].replace(',','')
        tform = AddTransactionForm(request.user, post)
        #...
```

(you can't change the request.POST dictionary itself as it's [immutable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict)).

Comment: It's not introducing any new security risks (it's not a nice way of doing it though - only do it if you really haven't time to handle the input in models with local settings).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what meaning you expect the comma to take.  Is it to be used as a thousands separator, or do you want to enable locale based input of numbers.

Let's assume we're talking about a decimal number representing one thousand dollars and twenty three cents.

In the `en-us` locale, this could be represented by `1000.23` or when using a thousands separator as `1,000.23`.  Some locales use a comma to mark the decimal separator so in the `de-de` (German) locale for example, this number could be represented as `1000,23` or `1.000,23`.

As you can see from the example, the comma can have two separate meanings.

If you want to allow the entry of the thousands separator in form fields, set [USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR) in your `settings.py` file.  If in the `en-us` locale, a user will be able to enter the number `1,000.23` or `1000.23` to represent the same number.  In the `de-de` locale, this will allow the entry of a dot for the thousands separator.

The default Django locale is `en-us`.  If you want to also support other locales and entry of different number formats according to locale, you have to add `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.  This middleware will look at the HTTP `Accept-Language` request header and set up the locale settings on a per-request basis, allowing your users to enter numbers in their own locale without you having to make any changes to your code.

As an aside, if no error is being rendered against your decimal field, then it's likely you also have a problem in your view code.  For example, the form may be created but due to an erroneous code path, a call to `is_valid()` is not made.  The resulting POSTed form would then just render a form without the list of errors attached.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. I will try it later, if it works I will mark your answer. Yesterday, I try many coding just to solve my problem but nothing happen so I hope your answer will work :)

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work, huh... When the system validate the DecimalField, it's doesn't allow the comma to pass.

Comment: @catherine Have you got [USE_L10N=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-l10n)?  What is the form error being displayed?

Comment: yes, I did what you have said but still the form.is_valid() won't allow me to pass. Is there a way to capture that field before it pass and validate to form.is_valid()?

Comment: @catherine You shouldn't need to capture the field before calling `is_valid()`.  It's up to the field logic to correctly validate.  Add a `print tform.errors` after the failed validation and post the resulting error message.