# How to get form field value before passing the form validation?

Tags: django

My question is related to this link: [How to allow user to input comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320974/how-to-allow-user-to-input-comma)

So I'm trying to do all the possibility just to make it work. Now I'm trying to get the value pass when performing saving action before it validates by the form.is_valid().

I'm successfully get the value by doing this:

```
.........    
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST['process'] == 'addtrans':
        tform = AddTransactionForm(request.user, 
                                   request.POST)

        print tform.fields['amount'] // this is the value that I want to get

        if tform.is_valid():
..........
```

But sadly the output is this:

```
<django.forms.fields.DecimalField object at 0x7fcc84fd2c50>
```

How to get the exact value or decode that output? I hope someone have tried this one.

Comment: You would get raw input with `request.POST.get('amount')`. `tform.fields` will have appropriate objects for the values.

Comment: yeah I already do that and I get the amount. I just want to get the exact parameters because I want to use it to replace the current value pass by the POST

Comment: @Rohan do you know other way to replace the value pass by the POST?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you're describing -

```
def transaction(request): 
    if request.POST.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST.copy()
        if 'amount' in post:
            post['amount'] = post['amount'].replace(',','')
        tform = AddTransactionForm(request.user, post)
        #...
```

(you have to create a copy of the `request.POST` dictionary because it's immutable).