# Can I show/set the decimal separator required by Django DecimalFields?

Tags: django, decimal

I’ve got the following form in Django:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    val = forms.DecimalField(localize=True)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

with the following model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    val = models.DecimalField("Betrag", max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
```

My settings.py contains:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de-de'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR=','
```

When evaluating the form in the following way I am getting errors:

```
form = MyForm({'val':'10,5'})
form['val'].errors 
# [u'Enter a number.']
form['val'].value()
# '10,5'
```

Of course I do not get any validation errors if I use '.' as decimal separator.

1. Is there any way to show/set the decimal separator for the 'value' field of the form manually?
2. How can I get an overwiev of my locale settings?
3. Is there any way to change locale settings on the fly?

*** EDIT ***: I Tried to add to MyForm:

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(MyForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['val'].localize=True
    if __debug__:
        print self.fields['val'].localize
        print ("Separator: "+settings.DECIMAL_SEPARATOR)
        print ("Language: " +settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
```

When executing I am getting:

```
#True
#Separator: ,
#Language: de-de
```

Comment: Try to add this to you `settings.py`: `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = ','`

Comment: Already did that :) Nothing happens

Comment: My bad, didn't saw it.

Comment: you can change locale settings with [activate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.activate) and ask for current locale with [get_language()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.get_language)

Comment: Well, I have tried and it worked. But first it yields a 'Field mandatory' error because the form field is called `val` and you are have `value` at the initialization of the form. Try to change to this `form = MyForm({'val':'10,5'})` :P

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I have tried it in interactive shell (using manage.py shell) and i am getting evaluation errors. Is there any way to analyze this?

Comment: What kind of errors? What exactly are you doing? I tried your code and it worked for me. What version of Django are you using?

Comment: The errors are:

form['val'].errors 
# [u'Enter a number.']

I am using Django 1.4 

I started a project as usual, defined the models and so on. Now i am playing around in the manage.py shell to find out, what is possibly going wrong

Comment: [Make Django forms use comma as decimal separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203089/make-django-forms-use-comma-as-decimal-separator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an error with django shell/ ipython shell, that is why it did not work. I moved it to this post

[python django shell (ipython) unexpected behavior or bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243031/python-django-shell-ipython-unexpected-behavior-or-bug)

Answer (score 2):

Define the `form` class like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['val'].localize=True

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Is a little complicated but I think that should work.

Comment: Hint: for debugging purposes you can use python debugger `dbg`. Add this line wherever you want a break point and control it from the console where your server is running: `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()`. Beside, why didn't work? Did it yielded the same error? Did it print localize=True?

Comment: You have to add that to your `MyForm` class, not to `MyModel`.

Comment: Still remaining the same validation error. I am starting to become real mad at it. But I am really grateful for your help :)

Comment: Did you added it to your MyForm class and still the same error? Notice that in your edit you say you added it to your MyModel class

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28986/discussion-between-paulo-bu-and-profhase85)

Comment: @ProfHase85 check out this. Maybe you've already solved it but this is another approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203089/make-django-forms-use-comma-as-decimal-separator

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now I partially solved this: At least I know the problem is somewhere in the shell. If you like, you may reproduce it, just have a look at my answer

Comment: I did all my test in a real django app. So odd!