# django localization problems 1.5

Tags: django, localization, django-1.5

After the migration to the new django version from 1.2 I have found that my localization in templates does not work.
I have tried to recompile *.mo files - it's seems that translation data have been right processed but it did not helped.

May be somebody know this issue? Or may be, somebody know how to discover it? 
I even don't know how to reconstruct django locale environment in shell script.

How can I receive something like this in shell:

```
>> import django.utils.translation
>> django.utils.translation.gettext("some text that exists in locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po")
>> "translated text"
```

Comment: Watch out when you use locale in `django shell`. By default the `shell` assume en-en as the language as pointed out in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243031/python-django-shell-ipython-unexpected-behavior-or-bug/16243631#16243631

Comment: Seems I have found where the problem was - I sholud move locale folder to module (not to main folder). But it can be not very convinient :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [djangoproject documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations) All paths listed in `LOCALE_PATHS` in your settings file are searched for `<language>/LC_MESSAGES/django.(po|mo)`

so you can simply add the following line to your setting.py:

`LOCALE_PATHS = (PATH + "/locale",)`

where `PATH` is main directory of your project.