# Django localization - Different localization settings for numbers and strings

Tags: python, django, localization

My app currently only provides an English User Interface. All text is kept in English. However I want to display numbers following the German number notation. The reason for this is that I create an app for a company based in Austria, for which the company language is English. Whereas company language is in English, most of the users are used the German number notation, and the app is creating some .pdfs which will be sent to Austrian companies which are also used the german number notation.

I have this middleware which activates the django translation:

```
class InternationalizationMiddleware(object):
    """
    Middleware that sets the locale and activates translation
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_anonymous() == False:
            locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_GB')
            translation.activate('de_DE')

    def process_response(self, request, response):
            translation.deactivate()
            return response
```

This middelware has the result that the numbers are displayed in the forms using the german notation (which is good), but has also the effect that error messages displayed by the forms are also provided in German. Since my user interface is only in English, and most of the employees do not understand German, the form error messages should not be translated.

Any idea how to achieve this?

My settings are as follows:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

#supported languages
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
    ('en_GB', 'English'),
    ('de_DE', 'German'),
)

#number date format settings
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = "."
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = ","
NUMBER_GROUPING = 3

USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True
```

My form is setting the localize to True as follows:

```
def localize_fields(self):
        """
        set localization to True for all fields
        """
        for name, field in self.fields.items():
            widget_type = field.widget.__class__.__name__
            if widget_type != "DateInput" and widget_type != "DateTimeInput" and widget_type != "SelectDateWidget" and widget_type != "TimeInput": #do not localize date / time input widgets
                field.localize = True
                field.widget.is_localized = True
```

Comment: See some ideas in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203089/make-django-forms-use-comma-as-decimal-separator