# Django Admin Model Thousand Separator in Change form when using Grappelli extension

Tags: django, localization, django-admin

I am working on an internal Django project using the Grappelli Admin Theme. I am in Australia and would like to format decimal numbers above 999 as 1,000.00 2,000.00. I have added the following to my settings.py file and the Model field has been defined as a Decimal.

The Change List form displays the number correctly formatted. However, the changeform does not and retains the unlocalized format.

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'Australia/Queensland'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True
NUMBER_GROUPING = 3
```

I have found numerous similar posts such as [Make Django forms use comma as decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203089/make-django-forms-use-comma-as-decimal-separator)

And it does state

> localization does need to be turned on explicitly for every field. For a model form (including the ones used in the admin app), a convenient way to do this is to subclass ModelForm and turn on localization for each DecimalField

However, at this stage I just need the Admin Change Form to carry the localisation and I am not sure how to do this when the Grappelli extension is in play. And as I have mentioned the Change List Form does render the same field with the thousand separator as I had hoped.

Your thoughts would be appreciated.